# Using elimination: $2x - y =7$ and $y^2 - x(x+y) = 11$. The picture is my attempt but I was stuck at the end. What did I do wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Was supposed to find a way to solve the simultaneous equation using elimination: $2x - y =7$ and $y^2 - x(x+y) = 11$. Here is my attempt, but I was stuck at the end.

[image]

Comment: I think you might have better luck trying to eliminate $x$ in the second equation.

Comment: "*using elimination*" $\;-\;$ Except your attempt does not eliminate either variable. The final equation still includes *both* variables.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this system of equations in $x$ and $y$, I would suggest eliminating one of the variables.

From the first equation, we have $y=2x-7$.

Substituting this expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ into the second equation yields

$(2x-7)^2-x(3x-7)=11,\;$  or $\;x^2-21x+38=0$.

Now can you solve for $x$ and $y$?